# TChart axis increment actual value

Tags: delphi, teechart

I'm using TChart standard, version 8, and trying to find the actual TChartAxis.Increment value.  From the doc: "Axis Increment is the minimum step between axis labels... If there is not enough space for all labels, TChart will calculate a bigger one".
My problem is to find appropriate MinorTickCount value, or rather to coordinate it with the actual Increment. Because the default MinorTicks value (3) can looks strange if the increment is 5, for instance (in this case it's more natural to have 5 minor ticks).
Thanks.

For instance, I set Increment to 1 and MinorTickCount to 0, but TChart increases increment to 5. If I knew that, I would set MinorTickCount to 4.

Comment: This question would be far more useful if you had specific values, and example code.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with *CalcIncrement* method, for example:

```
uses Series;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Chart1.Align:=alClient;
  Chart1.AddSeries(TLineSeries).FillSampleValues();

  TrackBar1.Max:=10;
  TrackBar1.Position:=2;

end;

procedure TForm1.Chart1AfterDraw(Sender: TObject);
var tmpIncr: Double;
begin
  tmpIncr:=Chart1.Axes.Bottom.CalcIncrement;
  if Chart1.Axes.Bottom.MinorTickCount<>tmpIncr-1 then
  begin
    Chart1.Axes.Bottom.MinorTickCount:=Trunc(tmpIncr-1);
    Chart1.Draw;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.TrackBar1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Chart1.Axes.Bottom.Increment:=TrackBar1.Position;
  Label1.Caption:='Bottom Axis Increment: ' + IntToStr(TrackBar1.Position);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, surely I set Increment and MinorTickCount manually. But TChart can change the Increment to a "bigger one". And the probelm is to get this "bigger" value.

Comment: I missed the CalcIncrement method, which makes it possible. I just changed my reply above to reflect that. If you are interested I can send the full project.

Comment: Thank you again, but it seems that CalcIncrement always returns 1 in my TChart version.

Comment: @EugeneDonin in that case you could try v9 (aka v2014) fully functional trial version: http://www.steema.com/download/vcl